# Accessing the the telephone cellular network with a Pi and a GSM USB device

Tags: raspberry-pi, gsm

I would like some help/guidance for acquiring a GSM USB device for use with a Raspberry Pi.  I want to create a Python program which will listen for TEXT (or SMS in Europe) messages and reply with some specific data.  I'm pretty sure I can create the program but I am totally confused by the wide choice of GMS USB devices.  Basically I am only interested in TEXT messaging so high speed and data levels should not be important.

Can someone please provide some specifications or guidance?  Thanks....RDK

Comment: [there are 2$ modules](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32284777313.html) which [you can use without usb](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64270/connect-sim800-to-raspberry-pi-rx-tx). you can pair it with [uart-usb adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001944326348.html) in case you want to use USB

Comment: Thanks, I have friend who is using the SIM900 with an  Arduino system.  My desire to use a UBS GSM device is to avoid wires and boards hanging off of my Pi.  Your ideas are good and definitely cheap.  Thanks again..